# c++ to java conversion, a few questions

Tags: java, c++

I am converting a some C++ to java and have a small bit that I am unsure about
first question is what is tested for in the line

```
if (ampconst[i][0] || ampconst[i][1])
```

this in an example to the data in the array.

```
 static short ampconst[NUT_SERIES][2] = {
{0,0},
{0,0},
{46,-24}
};
```

and my second question is that the ampsecul array is far shorter than NUT_SERIES
so I am getting array out of bounds exceptions, the array terminates like so

```
static long ampsecul[][5] = {
{0  ,-171996 ,-1742 ,92025 ,89},
{1  ,2062    ,2     ,-895  ,5},
{8  ,-13187  ,-16   ,5736  ,-31},
{9  ,1426    ,-34   ,54    ,-1},
{10 ,-517    ,12    ,224   ,-6},
{11 ,217     ,-5    ,-95   ,3},
{12 ,129     ,1     ,-70   ,0},
{15 ,17      ,-1    ,0     ,0},
{17 ,-16     ,1     ,7     ,0},
{30 ,-2274   ,-2    ,977   ,-5},
{31 ,712     ,1     ,-7    ,0},
{32 ,-386    ,-4    ,200   ,0},
{33 ,-301    ,0     ,129   ,-1},
{37 ,63      ,1     ,-33   ,0},
{38 ,-58     ,-1    ,32    ,0},
/* termination */  { -1, }
};
```

so how could this be handled in java and what would the values be at these lines
when the array is out of bounds or how would C++ handle this.

```
ampsin = ampsecul[isecul][1] + ampsecul[isecul][2] * T10;
ampcos = ampsecul[isecul][3] + ampsecul[isecul][4] * T10;
```

thanks in advance for any advice.
This is the whole for loop too see the code in context.

```
for (i = isecul = 0; i < NUT_SERIES ; ++i) {
    double arg = 0., ampsin, ampcos;
    short j;

    if (ampconst[i][0] || ampconst[i][1]) {
    /* take non-secular terms from simple array */
    ampsin = ampconst[i][0];
    ampcos = ampconst[i][1];
    } else {
    /* secular terms from different array */
    ampsin = ampsecul[isecul][1] + ampsecul[isecul][2] * T10;
    ampcos = ampsecul[isecul][3] + ampsecul[isecul][4] * T10;
    ++isecul;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    arg += delcache[j][NUT_MAXMUL + multarg[i][j]];

    if (fabs(ampsin) >= prec)
    lastdpsi += ampsin * sin(arg);

    if (fabs(ampcos) >= prec)
    lastdeps += ampcos * cos(arg);
}
```

Comment: In case anyone else wants to try and analyze: `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/brandon/pyephem` to get the full source. The sources are from libastro and the goal is to do nutation calculations (whatever that is :))

Comment: `ampconst` has been significantly truncated in your example, compared to the original code in libastro.  Were you aware of this?  There should only be 15 `{0, 0}` slots in the whole table, corresponding with the entries in `ampsecul`.

Comment: yes I thought posting all 106 lines was unnecessary, once I understood the my first question every thing clicked into place. I'm pulling the source code from XEphem http://www.clearskyinstitute.com/xephem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (ampconst[i][0] || ampconst[i][1])
```

tests whether the first/second column in ampconst[i] contain non-zero (it is an early-out optimization: if both the constants are 0 then the calculation can be skipped)

> **Edit** I just found (google!) that this is a nutation calculation that has been adopted in quite a few places, but seems to be originally from a libastro.
>
> ```
>      hg clone https://bitbucket.org/brandon/pyephem
> ```

As far as the isecul index is concerned: apparently isecul should never grow to >= 15 (note that `i` is the loop variable, not `isecul`, `isecul` is incremented conditionally).

<sub><strike>However, seeing the 'terminator' (-1) value, I'd really expect a check some like</strike></sub>

```
if (ampsecul[isecul][0] == -1)
   isecul = 0; // ? just guessing :)
```

or

```
if (ampsecul[isecul][0] == -1)
   break;
```

Also, I get the impression that the first column of ampsecul is a range-based division, so somehow, there would be a binarysearch for the matching slot into ampsecul, not direct indexing (i.e. isecul=4 would select index 2 (2..8) not 4)

Are you sure you are getting the source code correctly? I looks very much like there are some custom indexers (`operators[](...)`) that you misssed out on? This would probably be about the same class/function that contains the terminator check like shown above.
 **Edit** from the linked source I get the impression that the code is very much intended as is, and hence isecul should simply not be growing >= 15

Comment: thanks for the reply, the code is a look up table to correct for the earths nutation (wobble) while rotating, when the ampconst table data is 0,0 then the values in the ampsecul table are used. and on closer inspection there are 15 instances of 0,0 in the ampconst table so that is the limiter. The code is very old originally for HP PA processor

Comment: Thx, that explains. See the observation made by @msandiford perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

That first if statement is testing the array entries for zero/non-zero.  In C/C++ a boolean is simply an int that is used in a special way such that zero is false and non-zero is true.

As for your second array question I haven't grocked it yet.  But understand that C/C++ does no array bounds checking (other than what may accidentally occur if you touch an undefined storage page), so unless there's an egregious error in the C++ code there must be something that limits references to the valid bounds of the array.